# Show Block on third level domain

Tags: 7, routes, blocks, uri

I realise that the title probably makes no sense - and that's because I'm finding it quite hard to explain this.  But I will try my best.

I have a block that is set to only display on these pages

```
explore/whats-on
explore/whats-on/*
```

However when I come to a URL such as

```
http://example.com/explore/whats-on/event-2
```

I don't get my block showing up on the right.

Not sure what I have to do in order to make this work.
I'm using the Block menu and setting "only set on these pages" in order to do this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem, when I do it I do get blocks only on specified pages and deeper than that.

Comment: This is strange, I have no idea why it would happen to me then...